# Hide dynamic div when overflow

Tags: html, overflow

Basically I have a div list with some divs which contains some images and texts

```
<div id='item-list' style="height: 700px; overflow: hidden">
    <div id='item-1' style="overflow: hidden"> *some images and texts* </div>
    <div id='item-2' style="overflow: hidden"> *some images and texts* </div>
    <div id='item-3' style="overflow: hidden"> *some images and texts* </div>
    ...
</div>
```

My item-list has a static height which I don't want to change. The item div are added in dynamically whenever a user creates an item, where newest items are prepended to the top of the list.

I want to hide those items whenever the item list exceeds the height of 700px. I try to use overflow hidden but instead of hiding the whole item div, it crops the item until the height limit.

Example: Now I have 10 items with icons and texts and the list contents exceeds the height, so instead of hiding the whole div of item-10, it crops item-10 div that I only can see the icons but not the text.

What should I do if I want to hide the whole of item-10? Note that every item has a different height which is determined by what the user keys in during the item creation.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe do some jQuery to check the heights of individual items.  Loop over all of your items and do something like this:

```
var $totalHeight = 0;
if( $("#item-x").height() + $totalHeight < 700) {
     $totalHeight += $("#item-x").height();
     $("#item-x").show();
} else {
     $("#item-x").hide();
}
```

Essentially, you would want to check the height of individual items, and see if adding the next item would put it over 700px.  If it won't, show the item, otherwise, don't.

If you wanted to get fancy, you could use jQuery to completely remove any items from the `<div>` that put it over your height limit.